# Error in x[is.na(x)] <- na.string : replacement has length zero when exporting data frame to openxlsx in R

Tags: r, openxlsx

I have an issue when I try to export a data frame with the library `openxlsx` to an Excel. When I tried, this error happen:

```r
openxlsx::write.xlsx(usertl_lp, file = "Mi_Exportación.xlsx")
```

> Error in x[is.na(x)] <- na.string : replacement has length zero

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem in a data frame, but, in my case, I was using the related `openxlsx::writeData`.
The data frame was generated using `sapply`, with functions which could deliver errors because of the data. So, I coded to fill with `NA` when an error were generated. I ended up with `NaN` and `NA`s in the same column.

What worked for me is conducting the following treatment before `writeData`:

```
df[is.na(df)]<-''
```

so, for your problem, the following may work:

```
df[is.na(df)]<-''
openxlsx::write.xlsx(as.data.frame(df), file = "df.xlsx", colNames = TRUE, rowNames = FALSE, append = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
usertl_lp_clean <- usertl_lp %>% mutate(across(where(is.list), as.character))
openxlsx::write.xlsx(usertl_lp_clean, file = "Mi_Exportación.xlsx")
```

This error may be caused by cells containing vectors. So, using `across` to modify the vector to character.
I posted this here for others in need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `writeData` function from the same package.
Check out `writeFormula` from the same package as well or even `write_xlsx` from the `writexl` package.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).